# Why is a density operator defined the way it's defined?

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix

It's stated that the density operator  is:

$$\displaystyle \rho =\sum _{j}p_{j}|\psi _{j}\rangle \langle \psi _{j}|.$$

But I don't understand why this is the way both in mixed state and pure state. What is the significance of each component in the density matrix besides the trace? And how different a pure state representation than the way a mixed one is represented in the operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're asking, but let me start...

Let's say we have a quantum state $|\psi\rangle$. What is it we can actually find out about that state? Everything is the result of measurements. Each measurement result corresponds to a measurement operator $P$, and that outcome is given with probability $\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle$. Essentially, those probabilities are everything we can access.

Now, note that we can rearrange that calculation
$$
\langle\psi|P|\psi\rangle=\text{Tr}(P|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|),
$$
so if we do the calculation in that way, we see that it's sufficient to always work with $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. Although this is a matrix, it actually contains less information than the state vector because both $|\psi\rangle$ and $e^{i\phi}|\psi\rangle$ give the same density matrices. In fact, that's important - that's telling you that global phases have no observable consequences.

Moving on, let's say that we're given a quantum state, and we're promised that either it's state $|\psi_1\rangle$ with probability $p_1$, or $|\psi_2\rangle$ with probability $p_2$ (we say it's one of an ensemble). Now what's the probability of getting the measurement outcome corresponding to $P$? With probability $p_1$ it's $\text{Tr}(P|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|)$ and with probability $p_2$ it's $\text{Tr}(P|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|)$. Hence, overall, the calculation is
$$
p_1\text{Tr}(P|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|)+p_2\text{Tr}(P|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|)=\text{Tr}(P(p_1|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|+p_2|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|))
$$
So, the great thing is that if we group together
$$
\rho=p_1|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|+p_2|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|,
$$
we just have to calculate $\text{Tr}(P\rho)$. This is true for any measurement, and the $\rho$ is independent of which measurement is being done, so that's the natural quantity to use. You *could* do the full calculation with an ensemble, but for large ensembles that's just creating extra work because the matrix $\rho$ has much less information (which you can see by the fact that many different ensembles give the same density matrix), and is therefore much less work to manipulate.

Comment: And where on the density operator do I see that the norma of a mixed state is smaller than 1?? How do I infer it from the density matrix?

Comment: @bilanush See [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5603/1837)